# Burmese speech to text conversion in android?

Tags: android, google-api, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, recognizer-intent

Can we add custom language for RecognizerIntent?

I have search many SO Question like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080401/is-there-a-speech-to-text-api-by-google

That solve my problem of using limited number of language during Speech to Text conversion.

My problem is that, I need to used Burmese(Local Language of Burma) Speech and convert it to text. any other help can be appreciated.

**UPDATE :**

Google's servers currently support English, Mandarin Chinese, and Japanese. 
[Speech Input API for android](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/03/speech-input-api-for-android.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google will unlikely support small languages any time soon. The only way to custom language is to train CMUSphinx model and use it with Pocketsphinx:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/

Answer (score 3):

I don't know for sure but have you tried using RecognizerIntent?

See [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html), there is a section to specify the IETF language see this [section](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_LANGUAGE).

There is also this api demo code which you could try: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html

I really don't know if Burmese is supported as it certainly is not listed as one of the default locales but speech recognition is different.

Have just found this project: http://code.google.com/p/recognizer-intent/ it is probably highly unlikely that Burmese will be supported out of the box but I think it is worth trying the api demo code and seeing what it says in the drop down box, good luck.