# Speech to text conversion for non-english language

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, cmusphinx

I am trying to implement naive speech to text conversion for non-english language. where user speaks in other language and text is also in the same language .Is that possible ? If yes can anyone help with the idea of how to implement it ?  Any Help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: *naive* or *na**t**ive*? if *naive*, just embed a video of paris hilton speaking. if native, i don't think you can implement it yourself, it's way too difficult you may wanna search the net for a service provider for this

Comment: @KatrinRaimond Can you suggest any ?

Comment: It is better to mention the language name

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Actually it is Sanskrit.

Comment: Hi Prabhakar, Did you start work on Sanskrit Speech to Text? And can you share repo with me so i can also contribute in that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unlikely any commercial speech recognition solution will support Sanskrit, so the only choice you have is to add support for Sanskrit into open source engine like CMUSphinx.

This is pretty straightforward, you actually just need to follow the documentation and you can get to the point. You also need to have a knowledge of the scripting language which will help you to cut manual work on some steps.

1. Read Introduction - CMUSphinx Tutorial introduction to become
   familiar with concepts of speech recognition - features, acoustic
   models, language models, etc.
2. Try CMUSphinx with US English model to understand how things
   work. Try to train with sample US English AN4 database.
3. Read about your language in Wikipedia
4. Collect a set of transcribed recordings for your language -
   interviews, audiobooks or record them yourself.
5. Based on the data you collected, create a list of words and a
   phonetic dictionary. Most phonetic dictionaries could be created
   with a simple rules with a small script in your favorite scripting
   language like Python. See [Generating a dictionary for details](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialdict).
6. Segment the audio to short sentences manually or with sphinx4
   aligner, create a database with required files as described in
   training tutorial [Training Acoustic Model For CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam)
7. Integrate new model into your application and design a data
   collection to improve your model.

If you have questions, feel free to ask. [This paper](http://www.ijert.org/view-pdf/11342/sanskrit-speech-recognition-using-hidden-markov-model-toolkit) also might be of help for you.

Related questions are:

[Burmese speech to text conversion in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051820/burmese-speech-to-text-conversion-in-android)

[Writing speech-recognition engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202698/writing-speech-recognition-engine)

[Is it possible to write a speech-recognition engine from scratch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653811/is-it-possible-to-write-a-speech-recognition-engine-from-scratch)

Comment: Check This paper link. Mention name please.